# printing error message after third substring is found

Tags: c++, string, spaces

Hello I am pretty new to C++. I have a question regarding the splitting of a string.

For example, I have a string like this

```
std::string str = "jump 110 5";
```

and between strings "jump", "110" and "5" can be as many spaces as there can be.

I want to save 110 in an `int` variable and if after the number 110 another number or character should appear then the loop should break.

So far I have removed all the spaces and saved 110 in a variable and printed it out and the number five get ignored.

How can I break or print an error message after 110 saying that the string is not valid?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::string str = "jump 110 5";
    size_t i = 0;
    for ( ; i < str.length(); i++ ){ if ( isdigit(str[i]) ) break; }    

    str = str.substr(i, str.length() - i );    

    int id = atoi(str.c_str());
    std::cout<<id;

     return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Second attempt..
Here is what I wrote to parse the values into a vector. if the vector has more than one set of numbers, it prints and error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>


int main() {

    std::string str = "jump 110 5";
    size_t i = 0;
    for (; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
            break;
    }

    str = str.substr(i, str.length() - i);


    // Parse str to id
    std::stringstream sstr;
    sstr << str;
    std::string tempStr;
    std::vector<size_t> id;   

    while (std::getline(sstr, tempStr, ' '))
    {
        std::cout << tempStr << std::endl;
        id.push_back(std::stoi(tempStr));
    }

    // print an error if additional numbers are in id
    if (id.size() > 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << id[1];
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "You're good";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Caution: There is an error if there are more than one spaces between 110 and 5.

***Original Answer:***
If you want `id` to have the value `110 5`, then id shouldn't be an int type because it can't contain spaces. If you want id to have the value `1105`, then you'll need to get rid of the spaces in the string "110 5" before assigning it to `id`, otherwise the value will be truncated when assigned to `id`.

This is what I did to get rid of the spaces to make `id` equal to `1105`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main() {

    std::string str = "jump 110 5";
    size_t i = 0;
    for (; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
            break;
    }

    str = str.substr(i, str.length() - i);

    // get rid of spaces
    std::string tempStr;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != ' ')
        {
            tempStr.push_back(str[i]);
        }
    }

    // Set the str object to tempStr
    str = tempStr;

    int id = atoi(str.c_str());
    std::cout << id;


    return 0;
}
```

If you really need to keep `id` as an `int` and make `110` and `5` separate, then I'd suggest making `id` into a `std::vector` and parse the string into the vector.

Comment: thank you for your answer. However I wanted Id to remain 110 and if after 110 there is another number then an error should be printed

Comment: @konoha Hmm ok I think I understand you better now. In that case you'll need to parse out the string in to an int vector. I would code it myself to demonstrate but I'm not very good at parsing.

Comment: I updated my answers with my idea of how I would do it. Let me know what you think

Comment: Thanks a lot and thank you for taking your time to provide me with an answer :)